# Unity2020.3.9f1c1 Hold On(busy for 03:29)

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[image: Why does this thing come up so often]

This thing is a bit annoying.

How do I get rid of it.

Whenever I open a project and open a C # file in Visual Studio.

First, a dialog box will appear saying that Visual Studio is being opened.

Then this dialog box will always be displayed.

And it won't go away.

I could just ignore it and continue with Unity.

But it's still a little annoying.

This is not a very serious problem.

But it's really annoying.

I searched Google for a long time and couldn't find the answer.

I hope someone can give me some hints.

Comment: The answer below should help, but sometimes Unity is just slow. You get used to it after a while, like Stockholm Syndrome.

Answer (score 2):

Disable **Compress Assets on Import** for faster loading.

[Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html)
[image]
And move project to a SSD or M.2

Comment: I'm sorry, man, what you said doesn't seem to work. I have added some descriptions. I hope you can take a look.

Comment: @冷面包 It only happens after unity update? Or did you loaded an asset that contain AssetDatabase.Refresh() in there code?

Comment: I just reinstalled this version of Unity on a newly installed system.  
This project was the first project I opened.  
This dialog is also triggered when I import a new resource.  
There is only a small amount of code in my project.  
And there's no such thing as "AssetDatabase.refresh ()."

Comment: My files are stored under the Chinese path.  
Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Don't thinks so. I did some digging. You can also try clearing unity caches in %APPDATA%\LocalLow\Unity\ and delete library folder in your project. https://forum.unity.com/threads/editor-keeps-reimporting-assets-without-changes.802236/page-2#post-7080469

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it later

Answer (score 0):

I changed the project name from Chinese to English.
Now the problem is solved.
This was not an issue in previous 2019 versions of Unity.
So I think it's a bug.

Comment: If you think it's a bug try to reproduce it and report it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project path and project name contains only English letters, this should help.

I had the same issue on Unity 2020.3.35f1. This helped me out.